# What happened to Hulk's rage?

Tags: character, analysis, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

It is understandable that Professor Hulk has really dealt with Banner and Hulk and have got the *"best of both worlds"* as quoted by himself. But, I would disagree to some extent from this statement. Clearly, he has got best of Banner but missed out significantly on Hulk's rage.

One of the biggest losses for Professor Hulk in *Avengers:Endgame* was losing Black Widow. When he hears about her death and that she would never come back, his rage doesn't come through. All he does is throw a bench in the lake.

Well, yes he goes to the battlefield but it seems doesn't play a significant part.

Question:

Why has Rage Hulk been kept silent in *Endgame*?

Comment: MCU hulk has never been shown to get stronger as he gets angrier, so it's questionable if this iconic part of the character is even applicable to the MCU.

Comment: Everyone deal with loss in their own ways... I kicked my bedside lamp after I saw a spoiler that Tony Stark is dead. so.....

Comment: In the comics I think it was a give-and-take.  Professor Hulk was stronger than Banner, but weaker than Hulk, and smarter than Hulk but dumber than Banner.  I don't think anything ever put a number on it, but you could maybe think of it as like 80% of the strength and intellect.  Still really strong, still really smart, but not as strong or smart as he could be individually.  Worse yet, I recall his getting really angry reverted him to Banner's body (maximum weak) and Hulk's mind (maximum dumb).

Answer (score 7):

> Clearly, he has got best of Banner but missed out significantly on Hulk's rage.

### No....it's still there...just controlled.

As Banner said in *The Avengers*

> "That's my secret Cap, **I'm always angry**.

What's missing is the uncontrollability of the Hulk to properly direct the anger when **raging.**

Arguably, a hero with the strength and capabilities of the Hulk with the intellect of Banner is a positive thing.

Uncontrolled rage and lashing out... *not so much*!

Comment: I doubt the statement in Avengers(2012) -- *That's my secret Cap, I'm always angry*  --holds true in Avengers:Endgame too. I say this because in Endgame, Banner is at peace with Hulk and *much happier* than we have ever seen Hulk in MCU.

Answer (score 2):

### The Hulk's anger was far more of a liability than a help in almost all contexts.

In *The Incredible Hulk* it's mentioned that the Hulk killed at least six innocent people while on the run, including two scientists, an army officer, a police officer, and a couple of hunters who shot at him.

In *The Avengers* a minor bit of mental manipulation from Loki's scepter causes the Hulk to run out of control, nearly killing Black Widow, fighting with Thor, causing significant damage to the S.H.I.E.L.D. helicarrier, and almost killing some poor fighter pilot to boot.

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron* a minor bit of mental manipulation from Scarlet Witch caused the Hulk to rampage through Johannesburg, South Africa, causing millions, if not billions, of dollars worth of property damage and only avoiding horrific civilian casualties through the intervention of Iron Man and a massive amount of sheer luck.

Even after gaining some measure of control over himself and even when not under mind control, the Hulk's anger still caused him to lash out at his own allies (punching Thor during the Battle of New York), require significant handling (Black Widow needing to calm him down after they fought HYDRA), act petulantly and unpredictably (refusing to help Thor on Sakaar), and create many, many problems.

Additionally, it's not clear that the new and improved version of the Hulk is actually weaker than the rage-filled monster that he once was. While he does not contribute significantly to the final battle during *Avengers: Endgame*, this largely seems to be due to the injuries he sustained using the Infinity Stones rather than a lack of anger.

Comment: I personally wouldn't count "a couple of hunters who shot at him" as "innocent people", but I see your point.